# Запись из формы на странице при отправке каждый раз в рандомный txt

Tags: php, html

Есть два файла index.php и lib.php

Код в index.php

```
<body>
    <?php 
        require_once 'lib.php';
    ?>
    <form action="index.php" method="post" target="_self"></form>   
        <input type="text" name="user_name" id="">
        <input type="text" name="user_tel" id="">
        <input type="submit" name="btn" id="" value="Send">
    </form>
</body>
```

lib.php

```
<? php
function testPost() {
    if ($_POST["btn"]) {
        $rez = "";
        if (trim($_POST["user_name"])=="") $rez = "Error!";
        else if (trim($_POST["user_tel"])=="") $rez = "Error!";
        else {
            $info = "Name: ".trim($_POST["user_name"]).
                    "Tel: ".trim($_POST["user_tel"]);
                    $file_name = "request".rand(1000000,9999999).".txt";
                    $rez = "Ok!";

                    $f = fopen("./doc/".$file_name, "w");

                    if ($f) {
                        fwrite($f,$info);
                        fclose($f);
                    }

        }

        echo "that's Ok)";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Не знаю как исправить выводящуюся ошибку, задумка - чтобы пользователь ввёл свои данные в эти поля и они сохранились в текстовом файле в папке doc

Comment: Если убрать require_once 'lib.php'; и изменить action="index.php" на action="lib.php"?

Comment: Не помогло.. Поля появились, но сами файлы не создаются, видимо что-то с кодом не так, я с книжки списывал, не понимаю почему ошибка.

Comment: Надо часть кода, где происходит формирование файла и запись в файл, заменить на простой вывод текста. Просто проверить что скрипт срабатывает.

Comment: На данный момент содержимое файла index.php                                                                  <body>
    <form action="lib.php" method="post" target="_self"></form>   
        <input type="text" name="user_name" id="">
        <input type="text" name="user_tel" id="">
        <input type="submit" name="btn" id="" value="Send">
    </form>
</body>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
    if ($_POST["btn"]) {
        $rez = "";
        if (trim($_POST["user_name"])=="") $rez = "Error!";
        else if (trim($_POST["user_tel"])=="") $rez = "Error!";
        else {
            $info = "Name: ".trim($_POST["user_name"])."\n".
                    "Tel: ".trim($_POST["user_tel"]);
            $file_name = "request".rand(1000000,9999999).".txt";  
            /* вместо rand(1000000,9999999) лучше заюзать на выбор:
             *  - md5($info)
             *  - base64_encode(random_bytes(10))
             *  - date("YmdHis")
             */
            $rez = "Ok!";

            $saveBytes = file_put_contents(__DIR__."/doc/".$file_name, $info);         
            /* вместо fopen()..fclose() в php используют
               file_put_contents() */

                    echo $saveBytes;

        }

        echo "that's Ok)";
    }
?>
```

Если запись не происходит, то вероятен один из следующих исходов:

1. Неправильные права на папку или на родителей папки.
2. Неправильный контекст SELinux.
3. Закончилось место на жёстком диске или упёрлись в квоту на хостинге.

Comment: Спасибо, но пишет - Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION in Z:\home\upgraded_broccoli\www\lib.php on line 2

Comment: извиняюсь, в коде была еще одна ошибка. уберите пробел между `<?` и `php` чтобы получилось вот так `<?php`

Comment: спасибо тебе, а то бы никогда не заметил такую мелочь)

Comment: Ну обычно эта ошибка выводится, когда где-то по коду либо незакомментированный мусор, либо несоответствие закрывающих открывающим скобочек, либо пропущена точка с запятой `;`. Я имею в виду конкретно эту ошибку `Parse error`.

Comment: Сейчас ошибку не выдаёт, но файл тоже не создаётся, я в отчаянии, заливаю на файлообменник https://ru.files.fm/u/amsjje8c4#/

Comment: __DIR__ тоже не помог, зловещий файл так и не хочет сохраняться

Comment: а права на папку какие? папка `doc` сама то создана?

Comment: я понял в чем дело, уберите в начале файла строку `function testPost() {` и соответствующую ей закрывающую фигурную скобку `}` из `lib.php` и уберите `require_once 'lib.php';` из `index.php` - он там тоже не нужен

Comment: И из `lib.php` тогда можно настроить редирект на `index.php` если все прошло успешно вот этой функцией `header("Location: /index.php",TRUE,302);`

Comment: А функцию `testPost` кто-то собирается вызывать? Или вы думаете, что объявили ее и хватит?

Comment: Спасибо всем большое! Наконец-то получилось)